# PHP : The awk subtraction giving exponential values

Tags: php, awk, session-variables

I am getting awk result when I am subtracting two values, the error is I am getting exponent value 2.7755575615629E-17 instead of 0. Anything I am missing to apply, please suggest. These is happening with some cases only like 0.66, 0.67, 0.33,

The prototype of the code I am using is given below,

```
                    $_SESSION['x'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x'] - 0.83;
            echo ( $_SESSION['x']- 0.17) ;
            echo '<br>';
```

But on reversing the values It all fine with 0

```
                    $_SESSION['x'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x'] - 0.17;
            echo ( $_SESSION['x']- 0.83) ;
            echo '<br>';
```

Comment: What does this have to do with awk???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common problem in computer languages - float values aren't represented exactly. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems. If you have a particular amount of decimal places you want to exactly calculate with, you can use the `bcmath` functions in PHP:

```
$_SESSION['x'] = 1;
$_SESSION['x'] = bcsub($_SESSION['x'], 0.83, 10);
echo bcsub($_SESSION['x'], 0.17, 10);
echo '<br>';
```

Otherwise you can simply use your calculation and add an `round($result, $numberOfDecimalPlaces)` to you calculated result.

Comment: Thanks  it worked .. I was using round func but fgt to apply it after sub, I was doing it at division part only(in original code snippet) ..

Answer (score 3):

This is because its the floating point numbers. And as per the manual

"The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format). "

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Now there are 2 things which could be done by using the type cast your result to (int) or round up the result.

The other option is to use the [sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf)

Here is an example

```
$a  = 0.00001234;
echo $a ;
```

The output will be as

```
1.234E-5
```

Now if we do

```
echo (int)$a ;
The output is 0
```

or

```
echo round($a) ;

output will be 0
```

And finally if we do

```
echo sprintf('%f', $a);

We will get 0.000012
```